# No response when running --exec-after script

Tags: mysql, high-availability

In order to achieve high availability for MySQL database, I am using mysqlfailover utility. Everything is running fine when I am running

```
mysqlfailover --master=root:pass@master-host:3306 --slaves=root:pass@slave-host:3306 --rpl-user=slave-user:slave-pass --log=log.txt --force --daemon=start
```

And it produces following output

```
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Server 'master-host:3306' is using MySQL version 5.6.36-log.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Server 'slave-host:3306' is using MySQL version 5.6.36-log.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Unregistering instance on master.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Checking privileges.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Unregistering existing instances from slaves.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Registering instance on master.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Failover daemon started.
2017-05-15 12:41:06 PM INFO Failover mode = auto.
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO Master Information
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO Binary Log File: mysql-bin.000020, Position: 191, Binlog_Do_DB: N/A, Binlog_Ignore_DB: N/A
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO GTID Executed Set: 952b004a-3567-11e7-b46e-0a767d02b017:1-10
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO Getting health for master: master-host:3306.
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO Health Status:
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO host: master-host, port: 3306, role: MASTER, state: UP, gtid_mode: ON, health: OK
2017-05-15 12:41:09 PM INFO host: slave-host, port: 3306, role: SLAVE, state: UP, gtid_mode: ON, health: OK
```

When I am stopping master MySQL daemon, the output is

```
2017-05-15 12:40:01 PM INFO Master may be down. Waiting for 3 seconds.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Failed to reconnect to the master after 3 attemps.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM CRITICAL Master is confirmed to be down or unreachable.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Failover starting in 'auto' mode...
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Candidate slave slave-host:3306 will become the new master.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Checking slaves status (before failover).
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Preparing candidate for failover.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Creating replication user if it does not exist.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Stopping slaves.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Performing STOP on all slaves.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Switching slaves to new master.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Disconnecting new master as slave.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Starting slaves.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Performing START on all slaves.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Checking slaves for errors.
2017-05-15 12:40:16 PM INFO Failover complete.
2017-05-15 12:40:21 PM INFO Unregistering existing instances from slaves.
2017-05-15 12:40:21 PM INFO Registering instance on new master slave-host:3306.
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO Master Information
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO Binary Log File: mysql-bin.000003, Position: 191, Binlog_Do_DB: N/A, Binlog_Ignore_DB: N/A
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO GTID Executed Set: 952b004a-3567-11e7-b46e-0a767d02b017:1-10
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO Getting health for master: slave-host:3306.
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO Health Status:
2017-05-15 12:40:22 PM INFO host: slave-host, port: 3306, role: MASTER, state: UP, gtid_mode: ON, health: OK
```

But I want to execute a script after the switchover or failover is performed. Although the purpose of script is something related to database connectivity of my application but currently I am running a sample script **exec.sh** with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "creating a new file after failover"
touch troubleshoot.txt
exit 0
```

And now when I am running the command

```
mysqlfailover --master=root:pass@master-host:3306 --slaves=root:pass@slave-host:3306 --rpl-user=slave-user:slave-pass --log=log.txt --force --daemon=start --exec-after="./exec.sh"
```

it is stopping at **Unregistering instance on master** and the output is

```
2017-05-15 13:04:42 PM INFO Master may be down. Waiting for 3 seconds.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Failed to reconnect to the master after 3 attemps.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM CRITICAL Master is confirmed to be down or unreachable.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Failover starting in 'auto' mode...
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Candidate slave slave-host:3306 will become the new master.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Checking slaves status (before failover).
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Preparing candidate for failover.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Creating replication user if it does not exist.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Spawning external script.
2017-05-15 13:04:57 PM INFO Unregistering instance on master
```

Although the output says "Spawning external script" but nothing happened after this step. Also I checked that the script is having enough execution permissions as well as 0 exit status at the end. Please help me to find out what might be the issue which is stopping the further execution.

Comment: Probably stating the obvous but did you try providing the full path to your script instead of a relative path?

Comment: @lloiacono Yes, specifying the complete path worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to provide the full path to your script instead of the relative path.

```
mysqlfailover --master=root:pass@master-host:3306 --slaves=root:pass@slave-host:3306 --rpl-user=slave-user:slave-pass --log=log.txt --force --daemon=start --exec-after="/full/path/to/exec.sh"
```